# Oracle - Split polygon with line

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

How to cut a polygon with a line? I'm looking for an Oracle's function that can return polygons.

For example: If I have a square and a line going thru the middle, I would like to get the two polygons of the rectangles.

Looking for something like:

```
SELECT SDO_UTIL.SPLIT_POLYGON(POLYGON, LINE) FROM DUAL
```

Result can be wkt or an oracle geometry:

```
POLYGON ((-71.123456 45.123456, ....))
POLYGON ((-72.123456 46.123456, ....))
```

Comment: excellent question

Comment: @VBAHole Thanks, will be great to have a good answer too! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just recently came across this question. [Here](https://github.com/karinpatenge/spatial-scripts/blob/main/Vector%20data/Split%20polygons/function_split_polygon.sql) you can find a script, written by Dan Geringer, that splits a polygon into 2 separate polygons using a simple line geometry (containing 2 vertices).
I have tested the script using several polygons including polygons with holes, and multi-polygons. The test environment was an Autonomous Database 19c containing sample admin boundaries (polygons) for Germany.